# Ubuntu Mobile OS

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Android OS = Java

Windows Phone = C#

Apple = Objective C

Ubuntu OS = ?

Which language is used for developing mobile app in Ubuntu Mobile OS ?

Comment: Take a look at [App Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/)

Answer (score 1):

We use QML/Qt for native and also HTML5. That means the languages are C++ and JavaScript, the latter being used both for QML and HTML5 apps.